# How to get rid of the row numbers, to_csv?

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

after predicting the target value for the classification problem trying to get the predicted values in a .csv file along with the id of particular data instance but getting the unnecessary row numbers.

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y, random_state=101,strtify =y)

cls = DecisionTreeClassifier()
cls.fit(x_train,y_train)

pred = cls.predict(x_test)
prediction = pd.DataFrame({'id':x_test['id'],'target':pred})
prediction.to_csv("path/prediction.csv")
```

[x_test.head()  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dsbj.jpg)

[to.csv() image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz09z.jpg)

Comment: Include the data here instead of external screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `index=False` , [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) specifies this argument

```
prediction.to_csv("path/prediction.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: @VikasSingh - yes this would be enough